# How to correctly create a list of objects and then use these objects by index?

Tags: android, object, arraylist

I am trying to create a list of objects of another class in my program. I wish to be able to access a specific object in the list and then get data from the class using the object. Here is my class from which I am creating objects:

```
public class objectdata extends Activity {

    int number=0;
    String word="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public objectdata(int num, String word){

        number = num;
        word = word;

    }
}
```

Here is the class where the objects are added to the list and where I wish to access the objects:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    TextView tv;
    ArrayList<Object> objarray = new ArrayList<Object>(2);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        makeObjects();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void makeObjects(){

        //For loop creates two objects and adds them to the list
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            int number=1;
            String word="One";
            number++;

            objectdata o = new objectdata(number, word);
            objarray.add(o);
        }


        //THIS IS WRONG!
        //Access the second object in the list, so as to access the value in number
        objectdata o = objarray.get(1);
        tv.setText(o.number.toString());


    }

}
```

At the bottom is my attempt to access the object in index 1, so the second object which was created, I want to get the value in number from the class by using the object and store it in the text view so I can see it works. Basically I am trying to use objects to store data and then store these objects in an array list. I am completely stuck at this point.

Comment: And what actually goes wrong?

Comment: Well the code which I wrote, where I commented THIS IS WRONG, the code is wrong, and is giving me an error I cannot run it because I do not know the correct syntax for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to store objects of your own class inside the `ArrayList`, change the following declaration

```
ArrayList<Object> objarray = new ArrayList<Object>(2);
```

to

```
ArrayList<objectdata> objarray = new ArrayList<objectdata>(2);
```

Then your code should work. And by the way, `objectdata` is not a good name for a class, according to the naming conventions, a good name should start with an uppercase letter and use camel-case: `ObjectData`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help this was the problem! And thanks for the advice on naming my classes better, you are right!! :)